# lsyncd enabled service is not autostarting on PC restart - Active: inactive (dead)

Tags: server, kubuntu, kde, systemd, services

**I have super simplified the question by merging all the previous edits**

lsyncd config file `/etc/lsyncd/lsyncd.conf.lua`

```
settings {
    logfile = "/media/blueray/WDRed/_LsyncLog/lsyncd.log",
    statusFile = "/media/blueray/WDRed/_LsyncLog/lsyncd-status.log",
    pidfile="/media/blueray/WDRed/_LsyncLog/lsyncd.pid",
    statusInterval = 5,
    nodaemon = false,
}

sync {
    default.rsync,
    source    = "/media/blueray/Data/",
    target    = "/media/blueray/WDRed/_LsyncBackup/",
    delay     = 0, 
    exclude = { "/_RedoBackup" },
    rsync     = {
        binary   = "/usr/bin/rsync",
        archive  = true,
        compress = true,
        _extra = { "--backup-dir=/media/blueray/WDRed/_LsyncDeletedBackup/" },
    }
}
```

lsyncd service file `/home/blueray/.config/systemd/user/lsyncd.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Live Syncing (Mirror) Daemon
After=network.target remote-fs.target media-blueray-Data.mount media-blueray-WDRed.mount
Wants=media-blueray-Data.mount media-blueray-WDRed.mount
Requires=media-blueray-Data.mount media-blueray-WDRed.mount

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/lsyncd /etc/lsyncd/lsyncd.conf.lua
PIDFile=/media/blueray/WDRed/_LsyncLog/lsyncd.pid
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill $MAINPID
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Before Restart**

```
blueray@blueray-i58600K:~$ systemctl --user start lsyncd
blueray@blueray-i58600K:~$ systemctl --user enable lsyncd
blueray@blueray-i58600K:~$ systemctl --user status lsyncd
● lsyncd.service - Live Syncing (Mirror) Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/home/blueray/.config/systemd/user/lsyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-10-29 11:58:22 +06; 11s ago
 Main PID: 1921 (lsyncd)
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/lsyncd.service
           └─1921 /usr/bin/lsyncd /etc/lsyncd/lsyncd.conf.lua

Oct 29 11:58:22 blueray-i58600K systemd[916]: Starting Live Syncing (Mirror) Daemon...
Oct 29 11:58:22 blueray-i58600K systemd[916]: Started Live Syncing (Mirror) Daemon.
blueray@blueray-i58600K:~$
```

**After Restart**

```
blueray@blueray-i58600K:~$ systemctl --user status lsyncd
● lsyncd.service - Live Syncing (Mirror) Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/home/blueray/.config/systemd/user/lsyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
blueray@blueray-i58600K:~$
```

As you can see this service is working nicely if I give the command `systemctl --user start lsyncd`

Why it is not autostarting though I have given the command `systemctl --user enable lsyncd`. Why it is showing `Active: inactive (dead)` after restart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Systemd can be confusing with before's and after's but I would change:

```
After=network.target remote-fs.target media-blueray-Data.mount media-blueray-WDRed.mount
```

To:

```
After=network.target remote-fs.target media-blueray-Data.mount media-blueray-WDRed.mount network.target multi-user.target
```

based upon this [answer](https://github.com/google/cloud-print-connector/issues/140).

Answer (score 0):

Create lsyncd config file at (you can put it in other location too) `/home/blueray/.config/lsyncd.conf.lua`

```
settings {
    logfile = "/media/blueray/WDRed/_LsyncLog/lsyncd.log",
    statusFile = "/media/blueray/WDRed/_LsyncLog/lsyncd-status.log",
    pidfile="/home/blueray/.config/lsyncd.pid",
    statusInterval = 5,
    nodaemon = false,
}

sync {
    default.rsync,
    source    = "/media/blueray/Data/",
    target    = "/media/blueray/WDRed/_LsyncBackup/",
    delay     = 0, 
    exclude = { "/_RedoBackup" },
    rsync     = {
        binary   = "/usr/bin/rsync",
        archive  = true,
        compress = true,
        _extra = { "--backup-dir=/media/blueray/WDRed/_LsyncDeletedBackup/" },
    }
}
```

create lsyncd service file at `/home/blueray/.config/systemd/user/lsyncd.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Live Syncing (Mirror) Daemon
Requires=default.target
After=default.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/lsyncd /home/blueray/.config/lsyncd.conf.lua
PIDFile=/home/ismail/.config/lsyncd.pid
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill $MAINPID
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

**Debug Steps Motivation:**

As this sort of issue is plaguing the internet -

https://superuser.com/questions/955922/enabled-systemd-unit-does-not-start-at-boot

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237795/lsyncd-wont-start-at-startup

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374638/why-x0vncserver-is-not-starting-at-boot?rq=1

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98033/service-not-starting-at-boot

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282174/squid-systemd-service-not-run-at-boot

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255788/what-is-wrong-with-my-systemd-unit-file

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137028/why-is-my-systemd-unit-loaded-but-inactive-dead

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/376038/systemd-why-is-this-service-inactive-dead/376043

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159174/differences-between-inactive-vs-disabled-and-active-vs-enabled-services

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/376038/systemd-why-is-this-service-inactive-dead

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251211/why-doesnt-my-systemd-user-unit-start-at-boot

and many more.

I would also like to add the debugging steps which helped me solve the problem.

**Debug Steps:**

Step 1 is try to keep it simple.

Adding `media-blueray-Data.mount`, `media-blueray-WDRed.mount` etc. after

`After=, Wants=, Requires=` etc made things complex.

For User Services, use `systemctl --user list-dependencies` and/or `systemd-analyze --user critical-chain` to figure out what you want to put as `WantedBy=` under `[Install]` section -

**[NOTE:](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)** `[Install]` section is needed if you want to `enable` a service (run it at startup).

```
$ systemctl --user list-dependencies 

default.target
● └─basic.target
●   ├─paths.target
●   ├─sockets.target
●   │ ├─dirmngr.socket
●   │ ├─gpg-agent-browser.socket
●   │ ├─gpg-agent-extra.socket
●   │ ├─gpg-agent-ssh.socket
●   │ └─gpg-agent.socket
●   └─timers.target

$ systemd-analyze --user critical-chain

default.target @12ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
└─basic.target @12ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  └─paths.target @12ms
```

You can use the selected target with `Requires=` & `After=` under `[Unit]` section if needed.

Enable the service using `systemctl --user enable lsyncd`

If after restart your compute, the service is not running. Check the status of the service using `systemctl --user status lsyncd`

If you find error like **`lsyncd Start request repeated too quickly.`** in

Use `RestartSec=` under `[Service]`

**[NOTE:](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)**

> Takes a unit-less value in seconds, or a time span value such as "5min
>   20s". Defaults to 100ms.

You can also use something like

```
StartLimitInterval=10
StartLimitBurst=1
```

to address this issue.

After any change in unit files use

```
$ systemctl --user daemon-reload
// Disabling before enabling helped me. But I do not think it is necessary.
// $ systemctl --user disable lsyncd
$ systemctl --user enable lsyncd
```

**PS:** This was a brief debug guide. There are many articles on internet regarding this. Mine is not complete (There are a dozen more command which can help, namely `journalctl` with different attributes to read logs). But I hope it will help many beginners to use systemd.